# SUM Multiple Columns Values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I am not an expert on Oracle.
I have following table 'Fruits' on  Oracle 11 G DB:

```
Fruits:
DateTime    Fruit   Raw Rotten  Ripe
18-Jan-17   Banana  5   3   1
19-Feb-17   Banana  4   3   2
19-Jan-17   Banana  0   1   0
20-Feb-17   Banana  8   9   21
18-Jan-17   Apple   5   3   1
19-Feb-17   Apple   4   3   2
19-Jan-17   Apple   0   1   0
20-Feb-17   Apple   8   9   21
18-Jan-17   Mango   5   3   1
19-Feb-17   Mango   4   3   2
19-Jan-17   Mango   0   1   0
20-Feb-17   Mango   8   9   21
18-Jan-17   Guava   5   3   1
19-Feb-17   Guava   4   3   2
19-Jan-17   Guava   0   1   0
20-Feb-17   Guava   8   9   21
```

I want to write a query to give me the below output:
Desired Output:

```
DTM     Fruit   Total(Raw)  Total(Rotten)   Total(Ripe)
Jan-17  Banana      5           4               1
Jan-17  Apple       5           4               1
Jan-17  Mango       5           4               1
Jan-17  Guava       5           4               1
Feb-17  Banana      12          12              23
Feb-17  Apple       12          12              23
Feb-17  Mango       12          12              23
Feb-17  Guava       12          12              23
```

I have been trying to find some example related to situation I have but not getting there. Please, guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `TRUNC( datetime, 'MM' )` to truncate the `DateTime` value to the start of the month and then include this in the `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT TRUNC( DateTime, 'MM' ),
       Fruit,
       SUM( raw )    AS "Total(Raw)",
       SUM( rotten ) AS "Total(Rotten)",
       SUM( ripe)    AS "Total(Ripe)"
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY TRUNC( DateTime, 'MM' ), Fruit
```

Or you can convert `DateTime` to a string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( DateTime, 'Mon-YY' ),
       Fruit,
       SUM( raw )    AS "Total(Raw)",
       SUM( rotten ) AS "Total(Rotten)",
       SUM( ripe)    AS "Total(Ripe)"
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY TO_CHAR( DateTime, 'Mon-YY' ), Fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple group by

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DateTime), 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DateTime), 
       Fruit,
       SUM(RAW) as T_RAW, 
       SUM(ROTTON) AS T_ROTTEN, 
       SUM(RIPE) as T_RIPE
FROM TABLE_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FRM DateTime), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DateTime), Fruit
```

nb -- prior I showed how to do it in SQL SERVER:

```
SELECT MONTH(DateTime), YEAR(DateTime), Fruit, SUM(RAW) as T_RAW, SUM(ROTTON) AS T_ROTTEN, SUM(RIPE) as T_RIPE
FROM TABLE_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
GROUP BY MONTH(DateTime), YEAR(DateTime), Fruit
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hogan. Yes, it worked. I guess I was making my solution more complicated.

Comment: `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` are not valid Oracle functions - you get an `ORA-00904` exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DateTime), 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DateTime), 
       Fruit, 
       SUM(RAW) as Total_raw,
       SUM(ROTTEN) AS Total_rotten,
       SUM(RIPE) as Total_ripe
 FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY MONTH(DateTime), 
         YEAR(DateTime),
         Fruit;
```

Comment: `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` are not valid Oracle functions - you get an `ORA-00904` exception.